# After a farm restore, going to web application shows Sign In, Select credentials page

Tags: 2013, authentication, backup, restore, windows-authentication

I have a scratch SharePoint farm to use for testing and experimenting. I used Wrox's "Professional SharePoint 2013 Administration" to set up the farm.

I did a farm backup using the Central Administration (CA) interface and then a farm restore using the CA interface as well. The restore didn't 100% succeed because the User Profile Service Application was [running](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2762522) at the time. I stopped the application, did the restore, and it completed 100% successfully. I then started the User Profile Service Application.

Now, when I point a browser (whether on the SharePoint server or a separate client workstation) to either of my web applications (my.skunkworks.loc, portal.skunkworks.loc) I'm presented with a page that didn't appear before the restore:

[image: Sign In: Select the credentials...]

Any idea why this is appearing? I need to get this figured out before we start doing farm backups and restores in dev/test/prod.

-Jeff

Comment: did you check the what authentication method selected in the web application.from central admin > application management > from ribbon select authentication provider...

Comment: For both http://my.skunkworks.loc and http://portal.skunkworks.loc the **Zone** is _Default_ and the **Membership Provider Name** is _Claims Based Authentication_. For Central Administration the **Zone** is _Default_ and the **Membership Provider Name** is _Windows_.

Answer (score 1):

For each web application I changed the **Integrated Windows authentication** from *NTLM* to *Negotiate (Kerberos)*, clicked Save, changed **Integrated Windows authentication** back to NTLM, and clicked Save.

I'm not sure if anything else broke but at least this problem went away.

Thanks, Paul: [SharePoint | TechCenter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/08462862-6110-4499-aea3-330eed366531/sign-in-select-the-credentials-you-want-to-use?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: Here's a short version to solve this problem https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/08462862-6110-4499-aea3-330eed366531/sign-in-select-the-credentials-you-want-to-use?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious - open web.config and remove any extra provider in <Providers> section

Answer (score 0):

In Central Administration, click Manage Web application, select a web application that uses claims-based authentication, and then click Authentication Providers.

Select a zone that the web application is associated with to open the Edit Authentication page, and then click Save.

Repeat for each zone, and then for each web application that uses claims-based authentication.